# Traverse Up multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Currently i use

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().$(".collapse");
```

i tried to use .closest(".playerul") but it didn't find anything.
Passing a selector within the parent didn't work out either.
I have to go like this:
[image]

Comment: closest(".playerul") , you forget the dot ?

Comment: my bad.. i had it in the code... forgot to put it in the question tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var value = $(this).closest('.playerul').next(".collapse");
value.hide(); // to hiding 
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code to explain *how* this code answers the OP's question. This will also help future searchers.